React native 0.73 breaking version release
In the process of upgrading the react native version to 0.73.X I noticed that I had to remove this section from the android/app/build.gralde:
applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
        variant.outputs.each { output -> 
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here: 
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html 
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc. 
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4] 
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI) 
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants 
                output.versionCodeOverride = 
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi) 
            } 
 
        } 
    } 

Now when I generate a new build, it doesn't get multiplied by 1000 so it will come out a lower version code that I cannot publish on the Play Store.
If I try to restore the code to multiply it I get:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'abi' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl
How to restore the same logic?

What does your build.gradle file look like? You should have a version code field there.

it's the same as before, but during the build it get multiplied by 1000

Check this tutorial https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-releases/blob/main/docs/guide-release-process-0.74.md

The multiply is just a recommendation and not required anymore: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#VersionCodes
So you can just increase your versionName, since they will compare it first, like Ex: build 2(1.1) is greater than 1001(1.0)

The problem is that with the old version was multiplied by 1000 and now not, so the versionCode is lower and it's not accepted in the play store
